# C# Global variable for all forms

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, global-variables

I am a newbie programmer who is now developing application on C# with Visual Studio 2010 and many forms, so i am interested is it possible to set some global variables to use them in all forms ? Simple example, i have 10 forms, all of them are connecting to MySQL database, so it is not really smart to set 10 times database name and password when in ideal i can set in once and then use everywhere, i can't find answer to this question in google, so maybe somebody can help me here?
Is it possible?

Comment: Global variables are evil. Don't use them.

Comment: use settings http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/q/484635/38206

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a base class for your form, something that inherits from `Form`. Initialize the shared values there, to be accessible by the inheriting forms.

Answer (score 2):

There are few ways you can solve this.

- First you can use settings.
- Second you could use web.config (not sure    if this works in forms)
- Third option is to create a static class that    hold your variables.